# Mobile apps and authentication - B2C vs ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-identity, mobile-development

I have a ASP.NET Core project where I use ASP.NET Core Identity with individual user accounts. 
I am thinking of creating a mobile app that uses the same user repository, but it seems that mobile apps (ios or andrioid) only uses Azure AD B2C. That is basically all the articles on mobile apps and authentication that I can find.

Is this correct? If so - why?
Any input on this issue is appreciated :-)

Comment: Well mobile app usually incline, there will be a lot of users and Azure AD B2C just scalles better (out of box) and has better availability than your self-hosted Identity :P For scaling your app you need a lot more stuff to use (synchronized & distirbuted session store, i.e. Redis or similar, scaling up and down, distributed databases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Mobile App can use whatever they want to authenticate and authorization users.

Azure AD B2C is a solution for User Authentication and Authorization and it support many mainstream protocol such as OpenIDConnect and OAuth2.0, SAML.

You have accomplished the Authentication, what you want to achieve I assume is that Authentication as Service so that your PC applicaton, web application, mobile application can all authenticate the user using your asp.net core Identity.

There is already lot of mature solution for your requirement. mainstream is to use Identity Server 4 intergrating with Asp.net core identity. You can refer to this [document](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html) to have an basic idea of it